# How to set Python Tornado pretty log

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I write log from tornado like this:

```
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
```

And logs output without color:

```
[W 160803 17:04:32 test:68] warn
[E 160803 17:04:32 test:69] error
[I 160803 17:04:32 test:72] info
```

Even I call `enable_pretty_logging()` it is still no color.

Answer (score 0):

Color is used when two conditions are met:

- stderr is a tty (i.e. not redirected to a file or pipe)
- the `curses` module believes that color is supported (based on the `TERM` environment variable)

If `TERM` is unset, try setting `TERM=ansi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see source code of enable_pretty_logging about color format:

```
if (options.log_to_stderr or
(options.log_to_stderr is None and not logger.handlers)):
# Set up color if we are in a tty and curses is installed
channel = logging.StreamHandler()
channel.setFormatter(LogFormatter())
logger.addHandler(channel)
```

if you options satisfy the condition, the log will be colorful. Or you can just add the color format log handler no matter what situation.

```
from tornado.log import LogFormatter
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
channel = logging.StreamHandler()
channel.setFormatter(LogFormatter())
app_log.addHandler(channel)
```